# why do models vibrate when spawned into gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So many times as i've realized , why are the robots moving / vibrating themselfs inside gazebo? This is not good for a simulator... how can this be removed? For example right now i was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOssEL1xqNs) valkyrine robot in gazebo, and it is vibrating everything like it is afraid of something. so i asked right now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18572/why-do-models-vibrate-when-spawned-into-gazebo?/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Piggybacking off @Raskkii's [answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18572/why-do-models-vibrate-when-spawned-into-gazebo/?answer=18573#post-id-18573).

Some practical steps you can take to reduce/eliminate jitter:

- Check that your inertia matrices are realistic.
- Add damping to your links/joints.
- Add a small mindDepth value (~0.001) to links.
- Add a maxVel value.
- If applicable, make sure joint motors/forces are realistic.

This related [question-answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13506/preventing-bouncing-of-object/?answer=13515#post-id-13515) might also interest you.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shrutheesh R Iyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26374/shrutheesh-r-iyer/) on 2020-05-21**:
Hello. This is a very old question, and I came across it now. Could you please suggest how much damping to add? Approximately what order of magnitude? I dont seem to understand the concept well. I added random damping values, and my jitter did seem to stop, however, I feel like I just used a hack, without modeling the joints correctly. Is there any way for me to get it 'right'? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The video in question is sped up so while it looks like the robot is shaking quite violently, it is actually not that bad.

Generally, there are multiple reasons that can cause a robot to vibrate: bad inertia matrices, bad physics settings, problems with joints etc. The more complex the robot is the more difficult it is to prevent it from vibrating.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1